# two way binding for textarea having json object in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having one json Object which contains different components & this json object is used by layout-component to render components:

eg.

```
public user:Object={
    "name":"Bhushan",
    "address":{
        "data":"229 , MDC 4",
        "component":"AddressComponent"
    },
    "documents":[
        "Marksheets":[
            "SscComponent",
            "HscComponent",
            "EnggComponent"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Now I have given [(ngModel)] in following way to have two way data binding with textarea:

in view:

```
<textarea style="background-color:black;color:white;" [(ngModel)]="userData" rows="30" cols="120">
  </textarea>
```

in component:

```
//Getter & Setter Of userData
get userData() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.user, null, "\t");
}
set userData(v) {    
    try {
      this.user = JSON.parse(v);
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log("Invalid JSON Entered");
    }
 }
```

Now when I am changing something in my view , I can see userData gets changed in textarea.

but when I am copy pasting a new object inside textarea. it says 'Invalid JSON entered'.

P.S. Json is valid & all the components inside are loaded using compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync method.

all these components are inside one module & I am loading them using this json Object.

I want to be able to paste new json object inside textarea & all the components will get rendered accordingly.

is that possible?

any inputs?

Comment: Could you post your json Object and also do a `console.log(v);` and post the results

Comment: @FabioAntunes sorry unfortunately I cant make plnkr for this